# Filter list of tuples by date element and return tuple

Tags: python, date, tuples

I have a list of tuples with dates:

```
events = [('event1', 'Jan 15, 2010'), ('event2', 'Aug 4, 2015'), ('event3', 'May 1, 1999')]
```

I want to get the tuple with the most recent event. I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

recent = [e for e in events if max(dt.strptime(e[1], '%b %d, %Y'))]
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

How do I resolve or go around this?

Comment: You need to narrow down where the error occurs. I suggest writing a for loop instead of a list comprehension so that you can break it into several lines.

Comment: Be sure to look at the documentation for `max()` as you are not using it correctly.

Comment: The advantage of a list comprehension is the ability to use the max function on dates.

Comment: Agreed. A list comprehension is very useful here, but they are notoriously difficult to debug. I find debugging a for loop much easier.

Comment: Also, does it make sense to use `max()` on a **single** date? That is what you are doing here. You have all of the right pieces, but you need to arrange them differently to do what you want.

Comment: `max()` works fine this way: `[max(dt.strptime(e[1], '%b %d, %Y') for e in events)]` but it only returns the date. I want the whole tuple.

Comment: Yes, that is much closer because you are passing an iterable to `max()`. Note that you don't need the `[]` around it, though. As for getting the whole tuple, you need to pass the list of tuples to `max()` rather than just the list of dates. Then you also need to use the `key` argument to specify how to compare the tuples. See [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) for details.

Comment: Here's another link that can give you an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

try sorted :
`sorted(events, key= lambda x: dt.strptime(x[1], '%b %d, %Y'),reverse=True)`

you are passing a datetime to max function, it accepts only iterable

Comment: The OP is passing a `datetime` to `max()`, not a `str`. But the end result is the same. `datetime` is not iterable. Note that the problem only requires finding the max element, not sorting the list.

Comment: yes as you said..